# rmarkdown kable pander print matrix without border

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I have a character matrix:

```
df <- cbind(c("a", "b"), c("$\\sin\\theta$", "$\\cos\\theta$"))
df
     [,1] [,2]            
[1,] "a"  "$\\sin\\theta$"
[2,] "b"  "$\\cos\\theta$"
```

I want this table in a PDF document without any border. I tried kable which produced an error saying that it needs table heading. I also tried `pander` and `printr` which did a good job but I don't want any grid line neither inside or outside. How can remove all grid lines?

Comment: I found that it is generating `longtable` in my `tex` file with toprule and bottomrule. I just want to remove them.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I could us xtable, but I have to specify what type of table I need like HTML and LATEX. Instead I was searching for a function like pander or kable which will give out markdown or similar table so that pandoc will convert it into respective type as the document.

Comment: How big are your tables?

Comment: Not very big, but are wide and contains latex code too.

Comment: What is your final goal? Pandoc can translate from Latex to Markdown. But if you want a PDF Document it will nontheless end up using Latex even if you do net recognize it. Therefore, I do not see a reason why you shoud not use Latex directly.

Comment: I am preparing a document which I need in both HTML and PDF version where there are lots of tables. Some of them even have intensive latex equations. If I make it in LaTex I again make the same document on HTML and if I do it in HTML, I have to redo in PDF.

Comment: What if you just define a variable at the beginning of the document which specifies the table type? Then you would just have to change one line.

Answer (score 3):

I used the `xtable` package. With `xtable()` it is possible to control where you want to have lines.

````
---
pdf_document: default
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r results='asis'}
library(xtable)
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
df <- data.frame(cbind(c("a", "b"), c("$\\sin\\theta$", "$\\cos\\theta$")))
print(xtable(df),type="latex", hline.after = NULL, sanitize.text.function=function(x){x})
```
````

[image]